# Output formatting Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, output-formatting

So this is probably a very basic question about output formatting in python using '.format' and since I'm a beginner, I can't figure this out for the life of me. I've tried to be as detailed as possible, just to make sure that there's no confusion.

Let me give you an example so that you can better understand my dilemma. Consider the following program

```
list = (['wer', 'werwe', 'werwe' ,'wer we'])   # list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3]
list.append(['vbcv', 'cvnc', 'bnfhn', 'mjyh']) # list[4]
list.append(['yth', 'rnhn', 'mjyu', 'mujym'])  # list[5]
list.append(['cxzz', 'bncz', 'nhrt', 'qweq'])  # list[6]

first = 'bill'
last = 'gates'

print ('{:10} {:10} {:10} {:10}'.format(first,last,list[5], list[6]))
```

Understandably that would give the output:

```
bill       gates      ['yth', 'rnhn', 'mjyu', 'mujym'] ['cxzz', 'bncz', 'nhrt', 'qweq']
```

So here's my real question. I was doing this practice problem from the book and I don't understand the answer. The program below will give you a good idea of what kind of output we are going for:

```
students = []
students.append(['DeMoines', 'Jim', 'Sophomore', 3.45]) #students[0]
students.append(['Pierre', 'Sophie', 'Sophomore', 4.0]) #students[1]
students.append(['Columbus', 'Maria', 'Senior', 2.5])   #students[2]
students.append(['Phoenix', 'River', 'Junior', 2.45])   #students[3]
students.append(['Olympis', 'Edgar',  'Junior', 3.99])  #students[4]
students.append(['van','john', 'junior', 3.56])         #students[5]
def Grades(students):
    print ('Last       First      Standing        GPA')
    for students in students:
        print('{0:10} {1:10} {2:10} {3:8.2f}'.format(students[0],students[1],students[2],students[3]))
```

The output we're trying to get is a kind of a table that gives all the stats for all the students -

```
Last       First      Standing        GPA
DeMoines   Jim        Sophomore      3.45
Pierre     Sophie     Sophomore      4.00
Columbus   Maria      Senior         2.50
Phoenix    River      Junior         2.45
Olympis    Edgar      Junior         3.99
van        john       junior         3.56
```

So here's what I don't understand. We are working with basically the same thing in the two examples i.e. a list inside a list. For my first example, the print statement was:

```
print('{:10} {:10} {:10} {:10}'.format(first, last, list[5], list[6]))
```

where `list[5]` and `list[6]` are lists themselves and they are printed in entirety, as you can see from the output. **But that doesn't happen in the book problem**. There, the print statement says

```
print('{0:10} {1:10} {2:10} {3:8.2f}'.format(students[0], students[1], students[2], students[3]))
```

As you can see from the table output, here `students[0]` refers only to **'DeMoines'**. But if you just run the statement `students[0]` in the Python interpreter, it gives the whole sub list, as it should.

```
['DeMoines', 'Jim', 'Sophomore', 3.45]
```

So, basically, I've got two questions, why does `students[0]` have two different meanings and why does `students[0]` not print the whole list like we did with `list[5]` and `list[6]`?

Comment: If I may offer a suggestion: Try to shorten your examples and clarify the problem statement. You will get more attention if your questions are more to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the *for loop*:

```
for students in students:
#   ^^^^^^^^
```

So, `students`(inside loop) does not actually refers to **list of list**. And `students[0]` refers to **first element** from **element** from **list of lists**, as expected.

I suggest replace `students` from function argument, say, with `all_students` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand it a little bit now. So correct if I'm wrong, when we do a for loop applied to a list (or as it so happens in our case, a list of lists), it somehow changes the meaning of 'students[0]' (referring to the absolute first ELEMENT) when it's INSIDE the for loop. But, outside the for loop 'students[0]' still refers to the sub list.

Comment: A little correction: _"it somehow changes the meaning of 'students[0]'"_ - not somehow. Look at the for loop again. It has form `for <element_name> in <iterable_object>`. The main issue is that is your case `element_name` and `iterable_object` has same names.

Comment: @Kye Using `for x in x` is an awfully confusing construction. My guess is you'll be better able to see what's going on if you rewrite it as `for student in students`, like this: `for student in students: print('{0:10} {1:10} {2:10} {3:8.2f}'.format(student[0],student[1],student[2],student[3]))`

Comment: Thanks guys. appreciate all the feedback. I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the variable `list` into something that's not a reserved word or built-in function or type.

What's confusing to beginners - and it happens to everyone sooner or later - is what happens if you redefine or use in unintended ways a reserved word or a builtin.

If you do

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

you re-bind the name `list` to no longer point to the builtin `list` data type but to the actual list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in the current scope. That is almost always not what you intend to do. Using a variable `dir` is a similar pitfall.

Also do not use additional parantheses `()` around the square brackets of the list assignment. Something like `words = ['wer', 'werwe', 'werwe' ,'wer we']` suffices.

Generally consider which names you choose for a variable. `students` is descriptive, helpful commentary, `list` is not. Also if `list` currently holds a list, your algorithm might be changed later on with the variable holding a `set` or any other container type. Then a type-based variable name will be even misleading.

Comment: "you overwrite the definition and thus the meaning of the builtin `list` data type." - Wrong. The only thing you do when you name a variable like a builtin is shadowing the builtin in the scope of the variable (which is mostly not an issue in case of `list` because there's not many use cases for the type that can't be solved with a list comprehension or literal). The most important problem with calling the variable `list` is that the name isn't descriptive at all and doesn't give a reader any information about the variable or its contents except for the obvious fact that it's a list.

Comment: @l4mpi: It is correct that the meaning of the builtin list gets overwritten only in the scope of that variable. However it does get redefined. When answering questions of beginners sometimes it is good to not provide too much unasked for details. The point about unprecise and unhelpful variable names is also a good one, so I've edited both into my answer. Please reconsider the downvote (if it was done by you). Remember that SO is all about providing the best answers, and about constructive criticism. You could have just edited "scope" into the answer easily yourself...

Comment: @l4mpi: I have edited my phrasing again, as the word "redefinition" I used is indeed misleading. Thanks for the comment.